Seeking API for Real-Time Token Pricing and Market Cap on Solana ( Using Python)
Solana community!
I am developing a Python application that requires real-time data on cryptocurrency prices and market capitalization for specific tokens on the Solana blockchain. My initial research suggests that the native Solana JSON RPC API may not provide this specific data directly. Could anyone recommend an alternative API or method that integrates well with Python for accessing this type of financial information? Ideally, I am looking for something that allows for efficient and real-time data retrieval to support high-frequency trading algorithms.
Additionally, if there are any tips for using such an API with Python, such as library recommendations or code snippets, that would be incredibly helpful!
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

You should be able to use Raydium REST APIs - https://api.raydium.io/v2/main/price from Python to get realtime prices for tokens having liquidity on Raydium which should be a good chunk of tokens. You can also take a look at Jupiter SDK - https://github.com/0xTaoDev/jupiter-python-sdk?tab=readme-ov-file#-all-available-features

Hi, a question, I am using the raydium api but when I try to get the one for a specific token I get all the token information in raydium because it gives me somewhat large data, how do I get for a specific token? I am currently using https://api.raydium.io/v2/main/price/{token_id}

You can use Bitquery's API to get this data
Here are docs https://docs.bitquery.io/docs/examples/Solana/Solana-Raydium-DEX-API/
